wpdb->get_results returns incorrect ID for left join query
I have the following query using '$wpdb->get_results', I have an issue where the join of the second row of results changes the default ID (primary id in $shipping_table) from an ID of 2 to a value of 1.
If I set the column names instead of a wilcard it works. But I still want to know why using a wilcard is causing this behaviour. Any help appreciated.
Query
$items = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT *
    FROM `$shipping_table` s 
    LEFT JOIN `$shipping_type_table` st ON s.shipping_type_id = st.id 
    WHERE s.shipping_active = 1 
    ORDER BY s.shipping_order ASC;
");

Results (PHP dump)
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1368]
      public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_name' => string 'UK' (length=2)
      public 'shipping_amount' => string '10.000' (length=6)
      public 'shipping_type_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_order' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_package' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_type_name' => string 'fixed' (length=5)
      public 'shipping_type_active' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[1369]
      public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_name' => string 'USA' (length=3)
      public 'shipping_amount' => string '15.000' (length=6)
      public 'shipping_type_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_order' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_package' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_active' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'shipping_type_name' => string 'fixed' (length=5)
      public 'shipping_type_active' => string '1' (length=1)

if I run the same query in phpMyAdmin it returns the correct response (see below)

thanks
Nick

you have 2 columns whose name is ID, you need to disambiguate these with AS.

yes thanks i am aware that i have 2 columns with the same name of ID, but do not understand why its using the ID of the joining table? as I have other queries with left joins which keep the first ID column instead.

I read many people who said that the SQL standard define that the column order is not fixed and we don't have to rely on a particular order. but I don't find sources yet that confirms this in mysql documentation.

@mmm ok yes I was struggling to find any sources on this, weird how there is no consistency.

This is why you should specify aliases for columns like this - there is no guaranteed consistency.  It's nothing to do with php or wordpress - it's the way the database processes the query.

The reason of this is that you have two ID fields (both tables have an ID) and you select *. Since you have a single ID per items in the result set, the system will uses one of the two. It turns out that in your case it's using the wrong one.
To solve your problem, whitelist the fields, so instead of
select *

you should have something like
select s.ID AS ID, ...

defining what columns you want and aliasing them, especially the second ID.

thanks, do you know why it is taking the second ID instead of the first? is it related to the wpdb->get_results ?

@Nick it depends on how Wordpress handles the fields internally, which I did not debug, but I would guess that it loops the fields as it is getting and since s is the from table its fields are evaluated first and then come the fields of st. By the time the st fields are evaluated, among them the ID, the ID of s was already processed and the second ID overrides the first one. But this is speculation only.
